# How to fix "TypeError: printSong() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python

when I call the method printSong() I get an error message :

"TypeError: printSong() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

So.. what argument should I put inside the parentesis ?

I could remove "self" from the method printSong()... but then the method would not work...

```
class song:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ""
        self.artist = ""

    def printSong(self):
        return "The song " + self.title + " is song by " + self.artist

songs = {}

songs[1] = song

songs[1].title = "Gloria"
songs[1].artist = "U2"


@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    return songs[1].printSong()
```

I would like the homepage to just list information on the first song "Gloria",
in stead I get an error message :

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't instantiated the class:

```py
songs[1] = song() # need the parentheses here
```

Otherwise `song` has no `self` attribute because `__init__` was never called:

```py
s = song

# s is the class song, not an instance
s
<class '__main__.song'>

s.printSong()
# raises error because printSong is an instance method, but because
# you aren't calling this from an instance of the class, the instance
# isn't available to the method

s = song()
s
<__main__.song object at 0x10d7dbef0>
# Now s is an instance, and you can call instance methods because
# they have access to self
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to songs[1] = song()

```
class song:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ""
        self.artist = ""

    def printSong(self):
        return "The song " + self.title + " is song by " + self.artist

songs = {}

songs[1] = song()

songs[1].title = "Gloria"
songs[1].artist = "U2"



songs[1].printSong()


'The song Gloria is song by U2'
```

Comment: Yup.. spot on... I'm still learning how to work with OOP in Python :-)
You guys help me out a lot !  Thanks !